# How to access jenkins parent job build id in a MultiJob?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a requirement to trigger Automation Suite in multiple phases and summarize test results in a single test summary report.

I configured a Jenkins Multi Job to trigger my automation suite, which is divided in to multiple chunks say suite#1, suite#2, suite#3, suite#4 (each suite is a maven job) into 2 phases.

Phase#1 is a multi job having suite#1, suite#2 run in parallel and Phase#2 is another multi job having suite#3 and suite#4. While phases run in sequential.

I have trouble getting the parent build id, in my suite#1 job. This is needed for linking back the results to parent.

Eg: Parent Job - Build number is PB_001, 
      assigned into a custom variable myBuildNumber=PB_$BUILD_NUMBER
    Phase# 1:
         Suite#1 build number 101
         Suite#1 build number 201
    Phase# 2:
         Suite#1 build number 301
         Suite#1 build number 401

When ever I try to access myBuildNumber it is giving the current job Build number i.e as PB_101 rather than the one preserved in Parent job.

Please suggest if this can be achievable or not? I tried using Parameter Plugin/Pre Defined parameters still i couldn't get parent Build number.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this method to pass the build ID from a parent multi-job into the children jobs:

1. In the parent job, add a "Execute Shell" build step that saves the ${BUILD_ID} into a file, like this:

   ```
   cat > build.properties << _EOF_
   PARENT_BUILD_ID=${BUILD_ID}
   _EOF_
   ```
2. For the "MultiJob Phase" -> "Phase Jobs", add the child job and click on "Add Parameters", and select "Parameters from properties file". Enter "build.properties" as file name.

Make sure that the "execute shell" build step comes before the "Multijob" build step.
Now the child job will get the parent build ID as variable in ${PARENT_BUILD_ID}.

Note that the step (1) works for Unix build slaves; you may need to change it accordingly for Windows slaves.

Comment: Is there a better way to scale this method across n phased jobs? This requires adding a parameter to each job that needs it -- if all my phased jobs need the same value, it seems suboptimal to explicitly add the value to the add parameters section of each sub job.

Comment: I'm scaling it by using Job-DSL to define all my jobs (parent jobs and child jobs) - that way I can factor this part into a Groovy method and call it for every created job.